# Async Storage in React Native showing only first time saved data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, asyncstorage

I am trying to save data into async storage every time when data in redux store changes, But I am getting an error when I am trying to update user's Name and saving it then I am able to see the changes when Application is open but when I close the application and open it again then it is showing the Old User's Name that I have updated.

For example if my current Name is "Aviansh" and I have updated it to "Anshu" then I am to see "Anshu" when Application is open but when I close the application and open it again then I am able to see "Avinash" again that is not expected

Code for saving Data in Local Storage

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export const loadState = async () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = await AsyncStorage.getItem('socialReduxState');
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined;
  }
};


export const saveState = async (state) => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('socialReduxState', serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error has occurred: ', err);
  }
}
```

Code in Redux Store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
// thunk allows multiple actions to be run together
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from './reducers';
import { loadState, saveState } from './localStorage';

// Get existing state from localStorage
const persistedState = {};
// Create Store with data
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  persistedState,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

// Listen for any changes to the state and update localStorage
store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState(store.getState());
});


export default store;
```

Comment: Do you actually load the persisted state or are you really just loading an empty object with `const persistedState = {};`?

Comment: How do you load your previous state from AsyncStore? That's important. And should I suggest you to use `redux-persist` to store redux state? You're recreating the wheel

Comment: @NguyễnKhương Yes I am using Redux-persist, can you suggest a better way of using React-persist with async storage

Comment: @DrewReese I am not sure how I am loading, can you give me a idea, How can I load state every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned in the comments that you use `redux-persist`, but in the code sample you have posted, there is no `redux-persist` setup - this is what you are missing.

There is no need to save/load the data from async storage manually if you are using `redux-persits`, just follow the instructions in the [package readme](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#quickstart) carefully.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import rootReducer from './reducers'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const store = createStore(persistedReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk))
const persistor = persistStore(store)
  
export { store, persistor }

// Then use the `persistor` in your root app component:

import { PeristGate } from 'reds-persist'
import { store, persistor } from './store'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        {... your root app component here ...}
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```